# How to launch migration with wrong date format?

Tags: laravel, migration

Some time ago I created migration with date format like this 2019_2_090000. It worked ok, but today this migration dont work until name changed to 2019_02_090000. Is where any way to make migration work with old name? If name changed laravel recognizes migration as new which results in errors in old databases where this migration already executed.

Comment: how you added this `2019_2_090000` date format on your migration table?

Comment: change the filename and change the name in the `migration` table

Answer (score 0):

You can name your migration files however you want. When laravel runs them however, it depends on the filename to know which one comes first (they are run in ascending order). Just make sure to give them the filename you want **before** actually running them.

The reason is simple: when you run a migration, the filename gets saved to your database so you have to keep it consistent.

[image: php artisan migrate:status example source: bestin-it.com]

As long as you keep that in mind, you can use whatever naming convention you want.